# ¿Como se puedo autenticarme en SQL Server con host y puerto? (localhost,9999)

Tags: sql-server

Instalé SQL Server con versión de desarrollador.  Estoy tratando de autenticarme con los siguientes datos:

```
Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: localhost,9999
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
Login: sa
Password: ***********
```

No funciona, si solo ingreso como `Server Name: localhost` todo va bien, entro sin problemas.

Si, habilité el firewall para que acepte el programa para puertos dinámicos, en la configuración de SQL Server también habilité ese apartado, donde dice

```
MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP -> Enable -> Yes
```

También dentro de esas mismas opciones deje el puerto dinámico con un 0 (el mismo sistema señala que s debe dejar con 0 para indicar que se puede usar el ingreso de un puerto) y luego reinicie SQL Server.

El error que manda la autenticación que intento es:

> Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1225
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - El equipo remoto rechazó la conexión de red.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

El problema es que ya busqué por el error en la documentación de Microsoft e hice todo lo que aconsejan, pero sigue sin funcionar.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que te acepta la conexión utilizando únicamente `localhost`, podemos asumir que:

- La instalación es correcta
- La configuración del Firewall también lo es

Sin embargo, el SQL-Server está escuchando en el puerto default, que es el 1433.

Si quieres que escuche en otro puerto, debes configurarlo para el efecto, y no hablamos de puertos dinámicos, que son manejados y administrados por el propio SQL Server cuando tienes distintas instancias en un solo equipo. Como sea, la recomendación del propio Microsoft es utilizar puertos estáticos.

Para configurarlo, entra al *SQL Server Configuration Manager*, vé a *SQL Server Network Configuration*, selecciona la instancia que te interesa, da doble clic en *TCP/IP*, verifica que esté habilitado, ubica el parámetro **TCP Port** y cambialo al puerto en el que quieres que escuche, en este caso, 9999.

[image: Configuración de puerto]

Luego de este cambio, debes re-iniciar el servicio del motor de base de datos.

Si no logras conectarte, para verificar si realmente SQL Server está escuchando en el puerto, puedes valerte del comando

```
netstat -a -b
```

en la línea de comandos, que debiera producir una salida que liste a SQLServer como quién está a la escucha, por ejemplo:

[image: Resultado de netstat con SQL Server a la escucha en el puerto]

Requieres una línea de comandos como proceso elevado para poder ejecutar el comando con la opción `-b`, que es la que te permite incluir información de quién está a la escucha en qué puerto.

Una vez el SQL Server esté escuchando en el puerto que deseas, debieras poder conectarte a él sin inconvenientes.